# Finding the optimal number of prefixes for a Prefix Compression Scheme?

Tags: algorithm, prefix

Not sure if this applies more to Math Stack Exchange, but I have a CSV that has a list of strings -> [aaabbbcc,aaabbbcd,etc..]. I coded up a prefix compression scheme for each string where I place the strings into a trie and find the usage of each given substring (for example aaa appears in all the strings, aaabbb appears in 1/5). I am planning on replacing each given string with a compressed form where a single byte represents that string (aaabbb -> @). My question is how do I calculate the amount of prefixes I need such that I gain the most space saving. Each prefix mapped, adds the length of the prefix plus it's mapped char, so while aaabbb might be a good prefix (appearing in 20% of all entries), aaabbbc would not be.

Comment: There will not be much optimization possible in worst case scenarios where no string shares the same good length prefix.

Comment: Well in that case the optimal number would be zero, right? I just want to learn if there's an existing algorithm for reaching that number

Comment: Is the data sorted?

Comment: By the way, if the prefix encoding is done LZW style, where putting a prefix in the dictionary requires that all its prefixes already be present, the cost of extending a prefix much lower; each dictionary entry is just a prefix index and a character index.

Comment: Data is sorted by keys in alphanumeric order